# How to do append based on multiple filter on pandas dataframe more effectively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset `df1`

```
Id   Value  month   Year
1    672        4   2020  
1    356        6   2020
2    682        6   2019  
3    366        4   2021
```

Here's my dataset `df2`

```
Id   Value  month   Year
1    671        4   2020  
1    353        6   2020
2    682        6   2019  
3    363        4   2021
```

Here's my expected dataset `df` that is used `df2` from month=5 Year=2020 and before that using `df1`

```
Id   Value  month   Year
1    671        4   2020  
1    353        6   2020
2    682        6   2019  
3    363        4   2021
```

*Note*:
The original need is using pyspark, but in this question I'm exploring pandas alternatives

My Idea:

```
df1['code'] = df1['year']*100 + df1['month']
df2['code'] = df2['year']*100 + df2['month']
df1 = df1[df1['code'] =< 202004]
df2 = df2[df2['code'] => 202005]
df = df1.append(df2)
```

I think there's a way that do that more effective way

Comment: Please double check the data, you don't have 353/363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `mask`:

```
df = df1.mask((df1['month'].ge(5) & df1['Year'].eq(2020)) | df1['Year'].ge(2021), df2)
```

Output:

```
   Id  Value  month  Year
0   1    672      4  2020
1   1    353      6  2020
2   2    682      6  2019
3   3    363      4  2021
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the dataframes are aligned, you can use `combine_first`:

```
(df1
 .where(df1['Year'].mul(100).add(df1['month']).lt(202004))
 .combine_first(df2)
 .convert_dtypes()
 )
```

Or more simply:

```
(df1
 .where(df1['Year'].mul(100).add(df1['month']).lt(202004), df2)
 )
```

Output:

```
   Id  Value  month  Year
0   1    671      4  2020
1   1    353      6  2020
2   2    682      6  2019
3   3    363      4  2021
```

Otherwise your approach is correct, just use `concat` in place of append

```
df1 = df1[(df1['year']*100 + df1['month']) =< 202004]
df2 = df2[(df2['year']*100 + df2['month']) => 202005]
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```